# What does the two symbols (^ and $) stand for in Nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx

Can anybody help understand why there is `^` and `$`? I known `^` means "start with", `$` means "end with". I just don't know why we need that? Could you please list some URIs that match the following rewrite and show me the difference with or without the two symbols?

```
rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /show?user=$1? last;
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: Read the answer on the linked question, particularly on "Anchors" section.

Comment: I know exactly what the ^ and $ mean, I just need example to clarify them, that link is not clear for me my confusion. but still thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are present to ensure that the entire URL is matched when performing the rewrite.

For example, without the `^`, these URLs would match:

```
/admin/users/foo
/whatever/users/bar
```

In this case, the `$` isn't really required because the `*` is greedy (`.` matches anything and the `*` matches as much as possible). This results in the expression matching the remaining input even without the `$`. In a more restricted case such as:

```
rewrite ^/users/dan$ /show?user=dan last;
```

The `$` is important for the same reason. Without it, these URLs would match:

```
/users/dan/delete
/users/dan/profile
/users/danny
```

But with it, only the exact url `/users/dan` would match.

Comment: the reason why the ^/users/(.*)$ makes me confused is I think every request URI starts with /, now I understand  ^/users means " a request URI  starts with the whole part "/users" " , another reason is  I don't know why it still adds $, I also think it is not necessary  in this context, You have solved my years confusion. thanks.